# Configure Terminal for Mouse

Tags: mouse, gnome-terminal, ubuntu-mate

How can I configure my sessions in a terminal window (gnome-terminal, mate-terminal, etc) to process mouse clicks? For example, to move my cursor to another part of the screen.

Comment: I think you can't, never heard if such feature.

Comment: It happens automatically when I SSH into the same host, so I know it's supported in the terminal.

Comment: No, it depends on and is a feature of the client software you're using to connect.

Answer (score 1):

Individual applications (e.g. text editors) might enable mouse support. In that case they'll be notified about mouse events, and act however they wish to. For example, the *application* might decide to move the cursor to the click's location, or open a menu, execute some action (e.g. think of the top and bottom bars of `mc`), or do whatever else. You might notice that clicking in `mc`'s file listing area moves the currently selected file to the click location, but the *terminal's cursor* stays down there in the command line. Only in a fraction of cases is the desired user-facing behavior to move the terminal's cursor to the click's location.

There is no generic concept of enabling mouse support, since the cursor is expected to be entirely in the application's control. If it was moved by external means (e.g. the terminal emulator moving it on its own in response to a mouse click, without the application's request) then the application's subsequent behavior is likely to be incorrect: painting things at the wrong place. There is no way to notify an application that the cursor was moved by external means.

Some terminals try to figure out the intent of the click, and send keystrokes. E.g. if they recognize that you're in your shell editing a command line, and click within that command line's area, they synthesize the corresponding number of Left or Right keypresses that will cause the shell to move the cursor there. This approach sounds pretty fragile to me, probably breaks in a lot of cases. GNOME Terminal and MATE Terminal don't have such hack.

Answer (score 0):

I have just started to experiment with [Warp Terminal](https://www.warp.dev/), installed in Ubuntu. In the past I have been using the Gnome Terminal with Oh-My-ZSH configs and plugins. Warp, written in RUST, seems to have full mouse support (and other features such as AI). I installed it on my older laptop to see how it performs with a 940M GPU and a Gen4 i5 before using on the more powerful and modern desktop. The terminal seems to be responsive and fast, similar to Gnome Terminal. The downside is that you need to trust the company privacy policy as, their code is closed source; with promises to OpenSource some of the code for auditing and community development in the future.